# Run App gives no result R shiny app and crashes RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, web-applications, rstudio

I'm having an issue with the running of a R shiny app. Here's what I do:

1. open RStudio
2. load the shiny code (e.g. app.R)
3. set the wd
4. library(shiny)
5. press on "Run App"

Then nothing happens.

And if I try to terminate the execution, R does not answer anymore and says to force the closing of RStudio.

Here's one of my codes (I tried some, so I don't think this is the issue, but I report one anyway):

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Un'applicazione con uno slider"),
    sidebarLayout(
        h1("Sposta lo Slider!"),
        sliderInput("slider1", "Spostami!", 0, 100, 0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h3("Valore dello slider:"),
        textOutput("text")
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$text <- renderText(input$slider1)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do you have any advice to give me in order to make anything happen? I have no errors shown, so I don't know what to do...

I just see "runApp(...mypath.../app)" and blank space after it.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1:
I also tried this, but nothing happened (as before):

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

Edit 2: Copy-pasting the code directly in the console doen not work either

Comment: Copy-pasting this code directly in the console works for me. Does that work for you?

Comment: No, it does not. @RonakShah

Comment: What version of R and Rstudio do you have? What is your OS?

Comment: @Phil   R: 4.0.5; RStudio: 1.2.5033; OS: windows10

Comment: Try with a newer version of RStudio (current version is 1.4.1717). R is now at 4.1.0 but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Nothing changed @Phil

Comment: Very odd. As with Ronak, I can't replicate. What is your version of shiny? What if you try to install R 4.1 and install the latest versions of the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue with R 4.1 on Windows 10. Updating all packages seems to have solved it:

```
 update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```